# control charts plotting all dates in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, control-charts

I have problems with qic charts - control charts. 
my x.axis does not plot all the dates I want. I rounded the dates to every 14 days, and the period is of 59 weeks. I want all of these plotted, yet I have issues around that and could not find anything on that online. Yet, I am new to the control charts.

Here is an example, not the original data though, so the number of weeks are less here in this example but it does not matter as long as all dates are plotted.

Reproducing the data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:24, 4), 
ReportMonth = (rep(seq(as.Date('2014-1-1'),
                               length.out = 24,
                               by = 'month'),
                                4)),
             num = rbinom(4 * 24, 100, 0.5),
             denom = round(runif(4 * 24, 90, 110)),
             grp1 = rep(c('g', 'h'), each = 48),
             grp2 = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 24))
df
```

And plotting

```
qic(x= ReportMonth,
y= num,
n= denom,
data=df, 
chart= "i",
x.format="%Y-%m-%d",
x.angle = 90,
y.expand = 40, # where to start y axis from
xlab = "Month",
ylab= "Value")
```

I have tried with ggplot2 yet, I have not succeeded.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(plyr)

 p3.1 <- rename(p3, c("x" = "Date"))
 p3.1$Date<-as.Date(p3.1$x, format="%Y/%m/%d")

 plot4 <- ggplot(p3.1, aes(x = Date,y = y )) +
 geom_ribbon(ymin = p3.1$lcl, ymax = p3.1$ucl, alpha = 0.4) +   # fill = ""
 geom_line(colour = "blue", size = .75) + 
 geom_line(aes(Date, cl)) +
 geom_point(colour = "red" , fill = "red", size = 1.5) +
 #x.axis(1, p3$x, format(p3$x, "%Y-%m-%d"), cex.axis = 0.7)+
 ggtitle(label = "Readmissions within 30 days") +
 labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
 theme_minimal()+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

#aes(x = format(ActiveDate,"%Y-%m"), group = 1)) + geom_line(stat = "count") 
#+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) 

plot4
```

Comment: could you create a MRE: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I re-edited the question with examples. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to know how to plot your data frame, `df`, on a control chart using either `qicharts::qic()` or `ggplot2::ggplot()`?
I'm confused because the description of your problem doesn't match your example. For example, you say "period of 59 weeks" yet your `df` is 24 months (2014-01-01 to 2015-12-01).
Do you want us to ignore the description and just plot `df` on a control chart?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have came up with an example as the originaI data isn't to be exemplified. Thus, the number of weeks does not matter as long as all the dates in my example  are plotted. As you may see, not all the dates are plotted with qic function. Thus, I jumped to ggplot function believing I will be able to have all the dates plotted. but failed. Is there any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possible values to plot: `num` and `denom`. For simplicity sake I'm going to calculate the percent of these two values and plot `pct`. (But you can certainly choose to plot `num` or `denom` instead.)

Also, based on your data frame, `df`, you have four groups of values:

- Group 1: grp1 = g, grp2 = A
- Group 2: grp1 = h, grp2 = A
- Group 3: grp1 = g, grp2 = B
- Group 4: grp1 = h, grp2 = B

Part of the problem you are having is you need to plot each group separately, but you are not including these groups when you plot with `qicharts2::qic()` or `ggplot2::ggplot()`. To do so you have to first combine `grp1` and `grp2` into one group (`grp`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(qicharts2)

df_2 <- 
  df %>% 
  # calculate percent
  mutate(pct = round(num/denom, digits = 2)) %>%
  # collapse grp1 and grp2 to make single grp column
  unite(grp1, grp2, col = "grp")

head(df_2)
  x ReportMonth num denom grp  pct
1 1  2014-01-01  46   100 g_A 0.46
2 2  2014-02-01  54   105 g_A 0.51
3 3  2014-03-01  49   100 g_A 0.49
4 4  2014-04-01  56    94 g_A 0.60
5 5  2014-05-01  54   102 g_A 0.53
6 6  2014-06-01  48   106 g_A 0.45
```

It is perfectly fine to plot multiple groups on a line chart (time series).

```
ggplot(df_2, aes(x = ReportMonth, y = pct, color = grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%b '%y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

But you should *not* plot multiple groups on a single control chart. The control limits on a control chart are based on a single series (group's) historic values. If you plot all four groups on the same control chart you would get four sets of control limits which would make for a very confusing (almost impossible to read/interpret) control chart.

Instead you should plot four control charts, one for each group.

```
df_2 %>% 
  # nested dataframe
  split(.$grp) %>% 
  # apply qic
  purrr::map(~ qicharts2::qic(
    ReportMonth, pct, 
    data = ., 
    chart = "i", # choose an appropriate control chart
    title = paste("Group:", unique(.$grp)),
    xlab = "ReportMonth",
    ylab = "pct"
    ))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I could not find any parameter in `qicharts2::qic()` that specifies breaks (similar to the `scale_x_date(breaks = ...)` function in `ggplot`). See reference manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qicharts2/qicharts2.pdf).

However, a possible work around is to convert the date variable into a factor and use that instead. The downside to this approach is there is no line connecting the dots.

```
# Set levels for date variable -- ensure they are unique.
ReportMonth_levels <- format( unique(df_2$ReportMonth), "%b %y")

df_3 <- 
  df_2 %>% 
  # convert date variale to a factor with set levels
  mutate(ReportMonth = factor( format(ReportMonth, "%b %y"), levels = ReportMonth_levels))

df_3 %>% 
  qicharts2::qic(
    ReportMonth, pct, 
    data = ., 
    facets = ~ grp, # put all groups on one chart
    y.percent = TRUE,
    x.angle = 45,
    chart = "i", # choose an appropriate control chart
    xlab = "ReportMonth",
    ylab = "pct"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Note: I'm only showing one of the four control charts here. The code above will produce four separate control charts, one for each group.

Comment: hey jordan, thank you. I am not sure whether you have understood what I wanted. On the plots you have provided, I do not have all the dates plotted, which I am interested. I got all those qic charts with no problem, yet failed to plot all the dates. Apparently, the qic function takes only few of the dates and plots them.

Comment: yes, but not with all the dates in the data frame you have. Which I am interested in.

Comment: I think I understand your problem now. See my edit above.

Comment: thank you a lot, Jordon. If I find any answer to that I would let you know. Yet, it may be that ggplot2 has that function that puts a line on those graphs. I really hope those who created the library(qicharts2) would consider this issue.